# EDA playground ERROR VCP5294 "Undefined package uvm_pkg"

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm, edaplayground

I'm trying to compile a small UVM verification environment in [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/CfC2).

I'm getting this error:

> EDA playground ERROR VCP5294 "Undefined package uvm_pkg.

The code attached below:

```
 import uvm_pkg::*;

`include "reg_pkg.sv"
module testbench;
  reg  rst;
  reg clk;
  always #50 clk = ~clk;

  initial begin
    rst=0;
    clk=0;
    #100;
    rst = 1;
    `uvm_info("TESTBENCH",$sformatf("rst raised"),UVM_NONE);
  end
  
 reg_if reg_if_i();
  assign reg_if_i.clk = clk;
  assign reg_if_i.rst = rst;
  
  WriteRegisters WriteRegisters_i(
    .clk(reg_if_i.clk),
    .rst(reg_if_i.rst),
    .bus_en(reg_if_i.bus_en),
    .bus_wr_rd(reg_if_i.bus_wr_rd),
    .bus_data(reg_if_i.bus_data),
    .bus_addr(reg_if_i.bus_addr)
);
  initial begin
    uvm_config_db#(virtual mux_if)::set(null,"*","reg_if_i",reg_if_i);
    $dumpvars(0, testbench);
  end
  
  initial begin
    run_test("reg_test1");
  end 
endmodule
```

Do you know why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

When using UVM on EDA Playground, you need to explicitly select a UMV library version in the left side panel.  Currently "UVM/OVM" is set to `None`.

When I set it to `UVM 1.2`, the error goes away, as you can see below:

```
[2023-01-08 09:29:19 EST] vlib work && vlog '-timescale' '1ns/1ns' +incdir+$RIVIERA_HOME/vlib/uvm-1.2/src -l uvm_1_2 -err VCP2947 W9 -err VCP2974 W9 -err VCP3003 W9 -err VCP5417 W9 -err VCP6120 W9 -err VCP7862 W9 -err VCP2129 W9 design.sv testbench.sv  && vsim -c -do "vsim +access+r; run -all; exit"  
VSIMSA: Configuration file changed: `/home/runner/library.cfg'
ALIB: Library "work" attached.
work = /home/runner/work/work.lib
MESSAGE "Pass 1. Scanning modules hierarchy."
MESSAGE_SP VCP2124 "Package uvm_pkg found in library uvm_1_2."
```

Here is the modified [EDA Playgound link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/sCcP).

It is also helpful to look at the examples in the left side panel: Examples -> UVM -> UVM Hello World